# Why does StartTLS block connection to apache

Tags: openssl, apache

When I run this command:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.server:443 -starttls smtp
```

Why does Apache 2.4 & OpenSSL 1.0.1h(running on server 2008R2) stop responding to request from other machines ?

What I see when I run the command from the clients end:

```
openssl s_client -connect my.server:443 -starttls smtp
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001AC)
```

While OpenSSL is "CONNECTED" other connections from other workstations time out.

Any guidance would be appreciated

@Tom Leek, yeah I agree. So when I run the openssl command it sits at "CONNECTED", if ctrl+c I get the rest of the output from openssl

```
openssl s_client -connect my.server:443 -starttls smtp
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001AC)
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
bad select 10093
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
```

Comment: What do the Apache logs say? Anything in there that might be relevant?

Comment: @S.L.Barth With the Loglevel set to debug I see no real errors in the apache logs

Answer (score 5):

When I do `openssl s_client -connect myservername:443 -starttls smtp`, other clients are still supported just fine.

Of course, the connection from OpenSSL fails:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myservername:443 -starttls smtp
CONNECTED(00000003)
didn't found starttls in server response, try anyway...
140029862278800:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 330 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
zsh: exit 1
```

because the `-starttls smtp` instructs `openssl` to use the STARTTLS command as per the SMTP protocol, and my server is a *Web* server, that talks HTTP (and HTTPS), not SMTP, and it has no idea what "STARTTLS" may mean.

---

If connecting from a client and doing this (improper, unsupported) STARTTLS actually freezes your whole server, then you have a big problem (namely, a really easy denial-of-service) that deserves thorough investigation, especially since, to my knowledge and as per my own tests, Apache+OpenSSL does not in general suffer from that kind of bug. In fact, given that Apache forks several sub-process to handle clients, and each process handles several (many) clients in parallel, it would be surprising that a bug in handling incorrect data from one client would really block *all* clients.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two lines to my httpd.conf seems to have resolved the issue:

```
AcceptFilter https none 
AcceptFilter http none
```

The issue ended up not being specific to openssl but it did require the client to hold the connection open. I could create the same situtation using telnet.

```
c:\telnet myserver 80
```

Would block connections for other users as well